# What is the meaing of "for" as in "a rare visit for somebody”

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Trump seeks to project confidence on economy at New Hampshire rally](https://thehill.com/homenews/administration/457658-trump-seeks-to-project-confidence-on-economy-at-new-hampshire-rally)

> The rally marked a rare visit **for** the president to a state won by
>   Democratic contender Hillary Clinton during the 2016 presidential
>   race.

This "visit for the president" definitely is not "somebody made a visit for Trump."

So I wonder what that "for" exactly mean.

I looked up [longman dict](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/for), but there are tons of meanings for "for".

Comment: In this context, ***for*** explicitly connects ***rare** [visit]* to ***the president***. It's unstated whether it would be rare for *other people* to visit a state won by Clinton - the utterance simply asserts that *this* president has rarely done so (it's *rare **for** him to do so*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This use of the word "for" is unusual, but it is correct.

## It is rare for `X` to do `Y`

Here are some simpler examples that show the usage of "for" in this way:

> ✔️ **Yes:** It is rare for Twitter to ban specific advertisers.
>
> -- Jim Finkle, David Ingram, [Reuters News Service](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-twitter-kaspersky-lab-idUSKBN1HR2RM), 2018
>
> ✔️ **Yes:** It is rare for a player to combine the skills of power and speed.
>
> -- Baseball Hall of Fame (on Facebook)
>
> ✔️ **Yes:** It is a rare instance for a player to combine the skills of power and speed.
>
> -- Kevin Stiner, *"Ott’s first career home run an inside-the-park shot"*, [Baseball Hall of Fame](https://baseballhall.org/discover/inside-pitch/otts-first-home-run-an-inside-the-park-shot)
>
> ✔️ **Yes:** It is rare for a ballet's storyline to be overshadowed by science. So it is with “Anastasia”
>
> -- [*The Economist*, on Twitter](https://twitter.com/theeconomist/status/793007160544428033)
>
> ✔️ **Yes:** ..it is rare for a government entity to directly criticize a sitting member of Congress.
>
> -- Julie Hirschfeld Davis, [*The New York Times*](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/07/02/us/politics/white-house-twitter-kamala-harris-elizabeth-warren.html)

This is from a news headline, so it uses abbreviated "headline-speak":

> ✔️ **Yes:**  *Minnesota man catches a mystery fish; Rare for its color, remarkable for its age*
>
> -- [KSTP-TV, Minnesota, USA](https://kstp.com/news/minnesota-rare-bigmouth-buffalo-fish-brainerd/5381573/)

They are saying **"the fish is *rare* {for its color}"**.   Its color is unusual, so that makes the fish a **rare fish**.

The color makes the fish rare.

## In Your Example

Your example was:

> The rally marked a rare visit for the president to {a state won by Democratic contender Hillary Clinton during the 2016 presidential race}.

This can be reduced to:

> The rally marked a rare visit for the president to {`New Hampshire`}.

This can be simplified to:

> {`This was`} a rare visit for the president to New Hampshire.

**which is a complicated way of saying:**

> It is rare for the president to visit New Hampshire.